# How does one include the session-name in status bar for byobu-tmux?

Tags: tmux, byobu

I'd like to include the session name of my current tmux session in the status bar. There's nothing in ~/.byobu/status that allows me to do this and including the tmux configuration directive `#S` in the `tmux_left` line doesn't work (for obvious reasons).

Cheers.

Answer (score 15):

You can try this while using tmux:

`set-window-option -g status-left " #S "`